# Drive permission problem

Tags: permissions, mount

Re-installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, keeping the old drive partitions (/media/user/drive1 and /media/user/drive2). Given permission to current user with "`$sudo chown -R user:user /media/user/drive1`" after successful installation. Now some softwares not getting permission to open files from the drive. For eg: cannot open .aup file in audacity, showing 'permission denied to this drive' etc...

Kindly provide a solution.

-Jay

Comment: did you use "user" or your username? When issueing commands like this please use `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/user/drive1` so it is clear you are using your current user ($USER will be translated to your user when you use it but we get the benefit of knowing you used your own username without getting to know it ;) )

Comment: I used my user-name instead of '$USER:$USER' like: sudo chown -R mani:mani /media/mani/drive1

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the *default permissions* on the drive with `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -R -m u:$USER:rwX /media/user/drive1
```

If this isn't exactly what you need, I recommend looking up the man page of the command.